# PHPDoc and PhpStorm: indicate the return type of a magic method

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

In general, this is how I get my IDE (PhpStorm 2017) to recognize the type of a variable that I don't get to formally declare:

```
/*
 * @var User $user
*/
foreach($users as $user){}
```

The IDE knows then that `$user` is of class `User`.  Now I'm facing a situation with this line:

```
Yii::app()->user->login()
```

Specifically, the IDE has no idea what type `user` is. I get the warning:

> Field accessed via magic method

So I tried to specify with:

```
/**
 * @var User Yii::app()->user
 */
Yii::app()->user->login();
```

But that doesn't make a difference. How can I help the IDE resolve the type?

Comment: *"So I tried to specify with: `/** @var User Yii::app()->user */`"* -- it does not work like that -- this way you can typehint only first-level variable -- not a property of some another class. The best way is to go with @Dmitry's answer if you need such type hint only once (but it *may* have some side effects)). Otherwise do it locally via intermediate variable as @Nima suggests (but you will have to do it in every place where you will be using it).

Comment: An alternative but possible solution -- pass `Yii::app()->user` as a parameter to your class constructor/method call etc -- this way you can easily typehint internal class variable.

Comment: @LazyOne: "*The best way is to go with Dmitry's answer if you need such type hint only once*" Dmitry's answer seems to work everywhere `Yii::app()->user` appears, not just in one place.  I'm trying it with just his 2nd class (`CApplication`); don't know what the side effects would be

Comment: *"Dmitry's answer seems to work everywhere `Yii::app()->user` appears, not just in one place."* Correct. By *"type hint only once"* I meant that you need to typehint it in once place only. About possible side effects -- you most likely will see "This class defined multiple times" kind of notice (it's not as visible as Warning so should not annoy much + it can be disabled). 2nd possible side effect (it really depends on situation/context) .. that *sometimes* it may not offer you all available items in code completion popup (or you may even see "nothing to show" there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create in project phpdoc.php file and put next:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Yii
 * @method static CApplication app()
 */
class Yii extends YiiBase
{
}

/**
 * Class CApplication
 *
 * @property User $user
 */
class CApplication extends CModule
{
}
```

Comment: +1! A couple of questions: 1) If I remove the first class `Yii`, it still works. Is that needed? (`Yii` is already declared in a vendor library, as is `CApplication`). 2) does the filename *phpdoc.php* have any special significance?

Comment: I you removed first class and it still works, then its okay. phpdoc.php name is not special, it just shows than this file used for hints.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `Yii::app()->user` (or any other magic property) to a new variable and tell your IDE about that variable. Like:

```
/**
* @var User $user
*/
$user = Yii::app()->user;
$user->login();
```

Comment: Hey Nima. Upvote. Thanks, that's the only solution I could think of. I just wondered whether there is a more elegant one.